# How to export the config files of a content type to a module?

Tags: 8, configuration, layout-builder

I have a custom module. I created a content type and added some fields to that content type. I also enabled the layout builder on the manage display of the content type

Then I run `drush -y cex` to export the config files.

Then I copy all the config files related to my content type to the module's `config/install` director

Now if I make some changes to content type, their config files should be added/updated/exported in/to the module's `config/install` directory and should not be added to the site's default sync directory.

Is this possible?

Comment: But why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want a content should be in one module. It is installed on a site the content type will be there when the module is not installed that content type should not be there. I have multiple sites which shared codebase.

Comment: The same codebase is no problem, but you seem to have shared configuration if that's what happening.

Comment: Yes the configurations are shared that is why I do not want the content type should be there

Comment: @Marcel What I should do in this case? I do not want that content type on every site. While the code is shared. There around 300 sites. If the configurations are there in the sync directory, it will create the content type and its fields on every site when import runs. Therefore I wanted it to be in a module.

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly this with the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module.

> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal module except that it contains additional information in its info file so that configuration can be checked, updated, or reverted programmatically.

While ignoring the related config from configuration management with [Config Ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) at the same time. Which also takes wildcards so you don't have to enter every single config object by hand.

Comment: I will use feature for that module config and will use configuration management for all other configs?

Comment: @Ahmad – You additionally need config_ignore to exclude it from configuration management.

Comment: I will list all the config files of my module in the config ignore one by one?

Comment: @Ahmad – You can use wildcards.

Comment: OK and If I have created a feature with the config and is installed on the site. Then when I change the config files of that module, How it will be imported? with hook_update_N?

Comment: @Ahmad – With `drush -y feature:import MODULE_NAME` or similar. And export it with `drush -y feature:export MODULE_NAME`.

Comment: `field.field.node.service.*` entered this in config ignore but `drush -y cex` still export the service content type fields

Comment: even `node.type.service` entered in config ignore but it is exported also.

Comment: https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/drupal-8-configuration-management maybe you should read this post first.

Comment: @Ahmad – Yes, it's exported but it won't be imported. I'm thinking you should consider switching completely to Features. One module per content type, one for site config etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Drupal Console command:

```
drupal config:export:content:type page \
  --module="demo" \
  --optional-config \
  --remove-uuid \
  --remove-config-hash
```

Source: https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/config-export-content-type

Comment: I checked this but the `drush -y cex` still export the config to the default sync directory

Comment: You have to use this instead of drush and also notice the other options the console command provides which drush doesn't..

Comment: I'm running `drupal config:export:content:type application`  but it fails with the error: `// config:export:entity` and `[ERROR] The bundle application does not exist.` Any idea what's going on here? The _application_ content type has a bundle _application_type_

Answer (score 2):

You maybe misunderstand the drupal configuration workflow. A modules config files will only be installed when installing the module. At that moment the configuration will be imported in the database, and so, when you export the sites configuration your modules config will also be part of that. Subsequent changes to configuration of your own module can be done in update_hooks, but it's easier to make changes on the site self, export that, and have it versioned in that site's repo. If your module only holds config, you could also uninstall it immediately after you installed it, because it doesn't serve a purpose anymore.

So doing this, exporting config to a module, makes sense when you need that same configuration on another site that doesn't already have that configuration. Its a quick way to setup parts of the site the way you like. If a customer wants events where users can register to, and you created that before, you could create a module for that, that when enabled on the site sets up the basics for it. Further customizations to the clients wish on that particular configuration will be versioned in its own repo, when exporting the sites configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> After installing the Configuration Split module, the configuration can be exported in one or more "splits", enabling you to target different configurations for different environments or situations.

1. Install the [Configuration split module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) :

   `composer require drupal/config_filter drupal/config_split && drush en -y config_filter config_split`
2. Using the Backoffice create 2 splits one will export your module configurations  to `config/install` and the other will export other configurations into standard sync folder, a split enables you to :

   - Specify the exportation directory ex (`config/install`).
   - Specify what module configuration to export (your module).
3. just run **drush csex -y** and the code will be exported according to the split setup.

you may find these videos useful: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Configuration+split+module+

Comment: I used this method but there were some other config files also exported to that new location i-e `views.view.content.yml`

Comment: Isn't it `drush -y csex SPLIT_NAME`? Or does `drush -y csex` simply export all active splits?

Comment: `drush csex -y` will export all active splits that have been enabled in the setings.php